# "URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)" after exporting to android UI from figma

Tags: android-studio, user-interface, user-experience, figma, figma-api

I tried to export the Figma design to the Android UI of android studio, Once exporting was done. I opened the exported project In Android Studio. But it was showing a lot of errors.

In XML file,
It shows an error in xmlns,
error : "URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)"

I try to fix it by adding the URL to Schema and DTDs, but after that, it has shown an error again
error: "Resource registered by this URL is not recognized (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)"

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <!-- 
    /*
     *  This content is generated from the API File Info.
     *  (Alt+Shift+Ctrl+I).
     *
     *  @desc       
     *  @file       login_page
     *  @date       Saturday 06th of May 2023 05:16:55 AM
     *  @title      Page 1
     *  @author     
     *  @keywords   
     *  @generator  Export Kit v1.3.Figma
     *
     */
    -->
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/login_page" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/content_container" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/page_login_page_ek1"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <View   android:id="@+id/_bg__login_page_ek2"
                    android:background="@drawable/_bg__login_page_ek2_shape"
                     android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:layout_width="360dp"
                    android:layout_height="640dp" />

                <View   android:id="@+id/rectangle_1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_1_shape"
                     android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:layout_width="360dp"
                    android:layout_height="640dp" />


                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/standard_collection_8"
                    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/clip_path_group"
                        android:src="@drawable/clip_path_group"
                        android:contentDescription="clip_path_group"
                         android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_width="198dp"
                        android:layout_height="95dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/login"
                    android:fontFamily="Poppins"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/login_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="136dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="163dp"
                    android:layout_width="124dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:text="@string/login_string"
                     />

                <View   android:id="@+id/rectangle_2"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_2_shape"
                     android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="236dp"
                    android:layout_width="268dp"
                    android:layout_height="54dp" />

                <View   android:id="@+id/rectangle_4"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_4_shape"
                     android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
                    android:layout_width="268dp"
                    android:layout_height="54dp" />

                <View   android:id="@+id/rectangle_6"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_6_shape"
                     android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="424dp"
                    android:layout_width="268dp"
                    android:layout_height="54dp" />

                <View   android:id="@+id/rectangle_3"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_3_shape"
                     android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="236dp"
                    android:layout_width="54dp"
                    android:layout_height="54dp" />

                <ImageView android:id="@+id/rectangle_5"
                    android:src="@drawable/rectangle_5"
                    android:contentDescription="rectangle_5"
                     android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
                    android:layout_width="54dp"
                    android:layout_height="54dp" />


                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/frame"
                    android:layout_marginTop="251dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/vector"
                        android:src="@drawable/vector"
                        android:contentDescription="vector"
                         android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp" />

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/vector_ek1"
                        android:src="@drawable/vector_ek1"
                        android:contentDescription="vector_ek1"
                         android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:layout_width="22dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/email_address"
                    android:fontFamily="Poppins"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/email_address_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="107dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="233dp"
                    android:layout_width="138dp"
                    android:layout_height="59dp"
                    android:text="@string/email_address_string"
                     />

                <TextView android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:fontFamily="Poppins"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/email_address_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="345dp"
                    android:layout_width="98dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="@string/password_string"
                     />

                <TextView android:id="@+id/log_in"
                    android:fontFamily="Poppins"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/log_in_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="149dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="439dp"
                    android:layout_width="69dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="@string/log_in_string"
                     />


                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/frame_ek1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="345dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/vector_ek2"
                        android:src="@drawable/vector_ek2"
                        android:contentDescription="vector_ek2"
                         android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp" />

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/vector_ek3"
                        android:src="@drawable/vector_ek3"
                        android:contentDescription="vector_ek3"
                         android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:layout_width="18dp"
                        android:layout_height="21dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>


                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/frame_ek2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="439dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="204dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/vector_ek4"
                        android:src="@drawable/vector_ek4"
                        android:contentDescription="vector_ek4"
                         android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp" />

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/vector_ek5"
                        android:src="@drawable/vector_ek5"
                        android:contentDescription="vector_ek5"
                         android:layout_marginStart="-3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4.22dp"
                        android:layout_width="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="15.56dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <View   android:id="@+id/rectangle_7"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_7_shape"
                     android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="561dp"
                    android:layout_width="268dp"
                    android:layout_height="54dp" />

                <TextView android:id="@+id/sign_up"
                    android:fontFamily="Poppins"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/log_in_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="148dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="576dp"
                    android:layout_width="83dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="@string/sign_up_string"
                     />


                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/frame_ek3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="576dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="204dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/vector_ek6"
                        android:src="@drawable/vector_ek6"
                        android:contentDescription="vector_ek6"
                         android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp" />

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/vector_ek7"
                        android:src="@drawable/vector_ek7"
                        android:contentDescription="vector_ek7"
                         android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_width="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="15.56dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/forgot_password_"
                    android:fontFamily="Poppins"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/login_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="503dp"
                    android:layout_width="162dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="@string/forgot_password__string"
                     />

                <TextView android:id="@+id/or"
                    android:fontFamily="Poppins"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/login_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="168dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="540dp"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="31dp"
                    android:text="@string/or_string"
                     />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <!-- 
    /*
     *  This content is generated from the API File Info.
     *  (Alt+Shift+Ctrl+I).
     *
     *  @desc       
     *  @file       login_page
     *  @date       Saturday 06th of May 2023 05:16:55 AM
     *  @title      Page 1
     *  @author     
     *  @keywords   
     *  @generator  Export Kit v1.3.Figma
     *
     */
    -->
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/login_page" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/content_container" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/page_login_page_ek1"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <View   android:id="@+id/_bg__login_page_ek2"
                    android:background="@drawable/_bg__login_page_ek2_shape"
                     android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:layout_width="360dp"
                    android:layout_height="640dp" />

                <View   android:id="@+id/rectangle_1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_1_shape"
                     android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:layout_width="360dp"
                    android:layout_height="640dp" />


                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/standard_collection_8"
                    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/clip_path_group"
                        android:src="@drawable/clip_path_group"
                        android:contentDescription="clip_path_group"
                         android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_width="198dp"
                        android:layout_height="95dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/login"
                    android:fontFamily="Poppins"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/login_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="136dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="163dp"
                    android:layout_width="124dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:text="@string/login_string"
                     />

                <View   android:id="@+id/rectangle_2"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_2_shape"
                     android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="236dp"
                    android:layout_width="268dp"
                    android:layout_height="54dp" />

                <View   android:id="@+id/rectangle_4"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_4_shape"
                     android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
                    android:layout_width="268dp"
                    android:layout_height="54dp" />

                <View   android:id="@+id/rectangle_6"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_6_shape"
                     android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="424dp"
                    android:layout_width="268dp"
                    android:layout_height="54dp" />

                <View   android:id="@+id/rectangle_3"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_3_shape"
                     android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="236dp"
                    android:layout_width="54dp"
                    android:layout_height="54dp" />

                <ImageView android:id="@+id/rectangle_5"
                    android:src="@drawable/rectangle_5"
                    android:contentDescription="rectangle_5"
                     android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
                    android:layout_width="54dp"
                    android:layout_height="54dp" />


                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/frame"
                    android:layout_marginTop="251dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/vector"
                        android:src="@drawable/vector"
                        android:contentDescription="vector"
                         android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp" />

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/vector_ek1"
                        android:src="@drawable/vector_ek1"
                        android:contentDescription="vector_ek1"
                         android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:layout_width="22dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/email_address"
                    android:fontFamily="Poppins"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/email_address_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="107dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="233dp"
                    android:layout_width="138dp"
                    android:layout_height="59dp"
                    android:text="@string/email_address_string"
                     />

                <TextView android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:fontFamily="Poppins"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/email_address_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="345dp"
                    android:layout_width="98dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="@string/password_string"
                     />

                <TextView android:id="@+id/log_in"
                    android:fontFamily="Poppins"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/log_in_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="149dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="439dp"
                    android:layout_width="69dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="@string/log_in_string"
                     />


                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/frame_ek1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="345dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/vector_ek2"
                        android:src="@drawable/vector_ek2"
                        android:contentDescription="vector_ek2"
                         android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp" />

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/vector_ek3"
                        android:src="@drawable/vector_ek3"
                        android:contentDescription="vector_ek3"
                         android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:layout_width="18dp"
                        android:layout_height="21dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>


                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/frame_ek2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="439dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="204dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/vector_ek4"
                        android:src="@drawable/vector_ek4"
                        android:contentDescription="vector_ek4"
                         android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp" />

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/vector_ek5"
                        android:src="@drawable/vector_ek5"
                        android:contentDescription="vector_ek5"
                         android:layout_marginStart="-3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4.22dp"
                        android:layout_width="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="15.56dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <View   android:id="@+id/rectangle_7"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_7_shape"
                     android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="561dp"
                    android:layout_width="268dp"
                    android:layout_height="54dp" />

                <TextView android:id="@+id/sign_up"
                    android:fontFamily="Poppins"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/log_in_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="148dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="576dp"
                    android:layout_width="83dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="@string/sign_up_string"
                     />


                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/frame_ek3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="576dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="204dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/vector_ek6"
                        android:src="@drawable/vector_ek6"
                        android:contentDescription="vector_ek6"
                         android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp" />

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/vector_ek7"
                        android:src="@drawable/vector_ek7"
                        android:contentDescription="vector_ek7"
                         android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_width="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="15.56dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/forgot_password_"
                    android:fontFamily="Poppins"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/login_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="503dp"
                    android:layout_width="162dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="@string/forgot_password__string"
                     />

                <TextView android:id="@+id/or"
                    android:fontFamily="Poppins"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/login_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="168dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="540dp"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="31dp"
                    android:text="@string/or_string"
                     />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Another error in Java file:
The total code has an error!!!

```
/*
 *  This content is generated from the API File Info.
 *  (Alt+Shift+Ctrl+I).
 *
 *  @desc       
 *  @file       login_page
 *  @date       Saturday 06th of May 2023 05:16:55 AM
 *  @title      Page 1
 *  @author     
 *  @keywords   
 *  @generator  Export Kit v1.3.Figma
 *
 */


package exportkit.Figma;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class login_page_activity extends Activity {

    
    private View _bg__login_page_ek2;
    private View rectangle_1;
    private ImageView clip_path_group;
    private TextView login;
    private View rectangle_2;
    private View rectangle_4;
    private View rectangle_6;
    private View rectangle_3;
    private ImageView rectangle_5;
    private ImageView vector;
    private ImageView vector_ek1;
    private TextView email_address;
    private TextView password;
    private TextView log_in;
    private ImageView vector_ek2;
    private ImageView vector_ek3;
    private ImageView vector_ek4;
    private ImageView vector_ek5;
    private View rectangle_7;
    private TextView sign_up;
    private ImageView vector_ek6;
    private ImageView vector_ek7;
    private TextView forgot_password_;
    private TextView or;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_page);

        
        _bg__login_page_ek2 = (View) findViewById(R.id._bg__login_page_ek2);
        rectangle_1 = (View) findViewById(R.id.rectangle_1);
        clip_path_group = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.clip_path_group);
        login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login);
        rectangle_2 = (View) findViewById(R.id.rectangle_2);
        rectangle_4 = (View) findViewById(R.id.rectangle_4);
        rectangle_6 = (View) findViewById(R.id.rectangle_6);
        rectangle_3 = (View) findViewById(R.id.rectangle_3);
        rectangle_5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rectangle_5);
        vector = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vector);
        vector_ek1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vector_ek1);
        email_address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_address);
        password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
        log_in = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.log_in);
        vector_ek2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vector_ek2);
        vector_ek3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vector_ek3);
        vector_ek4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vector_ek4);
        vector_ek5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vector_ek5);
        rectangle_7 = (View) findViewById(R.id.rectangle_7);
        sign_up = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign_up);
        vector_ek6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vector_ek6);
        vector_ek7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vector_ek7);
        forgot_password_ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgot_password_);
        or = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.or);
    
        
        //custom code goes here
    
    }
}
```

[image: XML file Error]

[image: java file]

I Need help to solve this!! Kindly help me to sort out this issue.